# como capturar eventos con 2 teclas pulsadas?

Tags: javascript, keypressevent

Estoy tratando de que cuando el usuario pulse 2 teclas al mismo tiempo salga el mensaje de saludo hola por consola, si coloco una sola tecla si funciona, como lo hago con 2 teclas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Saludo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 17  && event.keyCode === 121) {
    return console.log("hola");
  }
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que quieres capturar Ctrl+F10 de acuerdo a los keycodes 17 y 121 (http://gcctech.org/csc/javascript/javascript_keycodes.htm)

Lo puedes hacer así:

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 121) {
    console.log("hola");
  }
});
```

Fíjete que lo que se comprueba es si esta pulsada la tecla control y luego el otro keycode. Lo que no puedes hacer es comparar que el keyCode que te llegue sea igual a dos números diferentes, porque si es igual a 17 no lo va a ser a 121 y viceversa, por lo que la condición de ese if siempre se va a evaluar como false.

También te he quitado el return con un console.log que no hace falta.